# Output a tuple within an STL list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

```
void output_list_contents(std::list<tuple<string, int, double,int>> &my_list)
{
    for(std::list<tuple<string, int, double,int> >::iterator it =my_list.begin(); it!= my_list.end(); ++it)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm trying to output the information from all tuples stored within an STL list. I don't know the syntax and I have spent the past hour googling for an answer, but sadly I haven't come across anything. I'm struggling with the syntax and logic to get access to the tuples stored within.

Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: Isn't `*it` the tuple stored within the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
void output_list_contents(std::list<tuple<string, int, double,int>> &my_list)
{
    for(const auto& e : my_list)
    {
        std::cout << std::get<0>(e) << " " << std::get<1>(e) << " "
                  << std::get<2>(e) << " " << std::get<3>(e) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is fantastic and works, but i would like to understand why it works. I would appreciate an explanation of "auto& e" or if you could provide me with a link that would help me understand.

Comment: @James It's called a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). The `const auto&` just bind the element based on what the container contains, hence `auto` deduces to the tuple in your example. `const auto&` is used instead of `auto` to avoid copying the tuples while iterating the `list`.

Comment: I understand how the auto works, and i understand how it goes through the list, but what is the value of e and what does this value do?

Comment: @James `e` (short for element) is just the `tuple`. It's like the iterator of your traditional loop, just that the iterator is conceptually a pointer to the element (which need to be dereferenced), while the range-based loop provide a reference to the element itself (with `const auto&`). `e` is different each time the loop is executed, of course (like an iterator which is advanced with `++it`).

Answer (score 2):

First overload `operator<<` for `tuple<string, int, double,int>`:

```
std::ostream& opertaor<<(std::ostream& out, 
                              tuple<string,int,double,int> const & t)
{
     return out << "{" << std::get<0>(t) 
                << "," << std::get<1>(t) 
                << "," << std::get<2>(t) 
                << "," << std::get<3>(t) << "}"; 
}
```

then use it in the loop as:

```
for(std::list<tuple<string, int, double,int> >::iterator it =my_list.begin(); 
                       it!= my_list.end(); ++it)
{
     std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Oh that is ugly. Better use range-based `for` loop and `auto`:

```
for(auto const & item : my_list)
      std::cout << item << std::endl;
```

Hope that helps.

---

A generalized implementation of `operator<<` for `std::tuple` would be this:

```
namespace detail
{
      template<int ... N> 
      struct seq 
      { 
         using type = seq<N...>; 
         template<int I>
         struct push_back : seq<N..., I> {};
      };

      template<int N> 
      struct genseq : genseq<N-1>::type::template push_back<N-1> {};

      template<> 
      struct genseq<0> : seq<> {};

      template<typename ... Types, int ...N>
      void print(std::ostream & out, std::tuple<Types...> const & t, seq<N...>)
      {
         const auto max = sizeof...(N);
         auto sink = {
                      (out << "{", 0),
                      (out << (N?",":"") << std::get<N>(t) , 0)...,
                      (out << "}", 0)
                     };
      }
}
template<typename ... Types>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, std::tuple<Types...> const & t)
{
   detail::print(out, t, typename detail::genseq<sizeof...(Types)>::type());
   return out;
}
```

This generalized `operator<<` should be able to print `std::tuple` with any number of template arguments, as long as all template arguments support `operator<<` in turn.

Test code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::make_tuple(10, 20.0, std::string("Nawaz")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::make_tuple(10, 20.0, std::string("Nawaz"), 9089) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
{10,20,Nawaz}
{10,20,Nawaz,9089}
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/2MQ0la) :-)

Comment: Thank you for your input, it gives me another view of the answer.

Comment: @James: I didn't give you any *input*. I gave you only *output*. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
void output_list_contents(std::list<std::tuple<std::string, int, double, int>>& my_list)
{
    for (auto tup : my_list)
    {
        print_tuple(tup);
    }
}
```

And this is how `print_tuple` looks:

```
template <typename... Ts, int... Is>
void print_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    auto l = { ((std::cout << std::get<Is>(tup)), 0)... };
}

template <typename... Ts>
void print_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& tup)
{
    print_tuple(tup, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

Comment: @James Do you have C++14 support?

Comment: Why is `std::index_sequence<Is...>` in the second `print_tuple`? It must be a typo.